# Segmentation Fault when trying to run blender

Tags: software-installation, cmake, blender

I have been working on this for several hours now and don't know where else to go. I originally started building Blender on my Ubuntu Desktop v 14.04 based on [this](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu/CMake) guide. Setting up git was no problem...at least as far as I can tell.

After trying to run `./install_deps.sh` I would get the following output at the end:

```
WARNING! ****WARNING****
If you are experiencing issues building Blender, _*TRY A FRESH, CLEAN BUILD FIRST*_!
The same goes for install_deps itself, if you encounter issues, please first erase everything in /home/david/src/blender-deps and /opt/lib
(provided obviously you did not add anything yourself in those dirs!), and run install_deps.sh again!
Often, changes in the libs built by this script, or in your distro package, cannot be handled simply, so...

You may also try to use the '--build-foo' options to bypass your distribution's packages
for some troublesome/buggy libraries...


Ran with:
    install_deps.sh 


If you're using CMake add this to your configuration flags:
  -D WITH_CODEC_SNDFILE=ON
  -D PYTHON_VERSION=3.5
  -D PYTHON_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/python-3.5
  -D WITH_OPENCOLORIO=ON
  -D OPENCOLORIO_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/ocio
  -D OPENEXR_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/openexr
  -D WITH_OPENIMAGEIO=ON
  -D OPENIMAGEIO_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/oiio
  -D WITH_CYCLES_OSL=ON
  -D WITH_LLVM=ON
  -D LLVM_VERSION=3.4
  -D CYCLES_OSL=/opt/lib/osl
  -D WITH_OPENSUBDIV=ON
  -D OPENSUBDIV_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/osd
  -D WITH_CODEC_FFMPEG=ON
  -D FFMPEG_LIBRARIES='avformat;avcodec;avutil;avdevice;swscale;swresample;lzma;rt;theoradec;theoraenc;theora;vorbis;vorbisfile;vorbisenc;ogg;x264;openjpeg'
  -D FFMPEG=/opt/lib/ffmpeg

Or even simpler, just run (in your blender-source dir):
  make -j1 BUILD_CMAKE_ARGS="-U *SNDFILE* -U *PYTHON* -U *BOOST* -U *Boost* -U *OPENCOLORIO* -U *OPENEXR* -U *OPENIMAGEIO* -U *LLVM* -U *CYCLES* -U *OPENSUBDIV* -U *COLLADA* -U *FFMPEG* -D WITH_CODEC_SNDFILE=ON -D PYTHON_VERSION=3.5 -D PYTHON_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/python-3.5 -D WITH_OPENCOLORIO=ON -D OPENCOLORIO_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/ocio -D OPENEXR_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/openexr -D WITH_OPENIMAGEIO=ON -D OPENIMAGEIO_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/oiio -D WITH_CYCLES_OSL=ON -D WITH_LLVM=ON -D LLVM_VERSION=3.4 -D CYCLES_OSL=/opt/lib/osl -D WITH_OPENSUBDIV=ON -D OPENSUBDIV_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/osd -D WITH_CODEC_FFMPEG=ON -D FFMPEG_LIBRARIES='avformat;avcodec;avutil;avdevice;swscale;swresample;lzma;rt;theoradec;theoraenc;theora;vorbis;vorbisfile;vorbisenc;ogg;x264;openjpeg' -D FFMPEG=/opt/lib/ffmpeg"

This information has been written to /home/david/Documents/blender/build_files/build_environment/BUILD_NOTES.txt
```

Naturally, I tried running the suggested command at the end of the warning:

```
make -j1 BUILD_CMAKE_ARGS="-U *SNDFILE* -U *PYTHON* -U *BOOST* -U *Boost* -U *OPENCOLORIO* -U *OPENEXR* -U *OPENIMAGEIO* -U *LLVM* -U *CYCLES* -U *OPENSUBDIV* -U *COLLADA* -U *FFMPEG* -D WITH_CODEC_SNDFILE=ON -D PYTHON_VERSION=3.5 -D PYTHON_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/python-3.5 -D WITH_OPENCOLORIO=ON -D OPENCOLORIO_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/ocio -D OPENEXR_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/openexr -D WITH_OPENIMAGEIO=ON -D OPENIMAGEIO_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/oiio -D WITH_CYCLES_OSL=ON -D WITH_LLVM=ON -D LLVM_VERSION=3.4 -D CYCLES_OSL=/opt/lib/osl -D WITH_OPENSUBDIV=ON -D OPENSUBDIV_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/osd -D WITH_CODEC_FFMPEG=ON -D FFMPEG_LIBRARIES='avformat;avcodec;avutil;avdevice;swscale;swresample;lzma;rt;theoradec;theoraenc;theora;vorbis;vorbisfile;vorbisenc;ogg;x264;openjpeg' -D FFMPEG=/opt/lib/ffmpeg"
```

Which produced

```
edit build configuration with: /home/david/Documents/build_linux/CMakeCache.txt run make again to rebuild.
Blender successfully built, run from: /home/david/Documents/build_linux/bin/blender
```

After trying to run `./blender` I received the following error:

```
found bundled python: /home/david/Documents/build_linux/bin/2.77/python
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here's the output

```
# Blender 2.77 (sub 0), Commit date: 2016-04-08 22:25, Hash d09a372

# backtrace
./blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x1d) [0x136fb1d]
./blender() [0xa201b8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x36d40) [0x7f7a25397d40]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.4.so.1(_ZN4llvm13EngineBuilder12selectTargetERKNS_6TripleENS_9StringRefES4_RKNS_15SmallVectorImplISsEE+0x1a7) [0x7f7a21a49dd7]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.4.so.1(_ZN4llvm13EngineBuilder12selectTargetEv+0x9c) [0x7f7a21a4a27c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so(+0x3b0629) [0x7f7a077a2629]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so(+0x3aec28) [0x7f7a077a0c28]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so(+0x3d0c4d) [0x7f7a077c2c4d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so(+0x3d2025) [0x7f7a077c4025]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so(+0x309e1f) [0x7f7a076fbe1f]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so(+0x30304f) [0x7f7a076f504f]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so(+0x303537) [0x7f7a076f5537]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so(+0x5b7fad) [0x7f7a079a9fad]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so(+0x3625e7) [0x7f7a077545e7]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so(+0x1d7d20) [0x7f7a075c9d20]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so(+0x1ab40b) [0x7f7a0759d40b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so(+0x18e44a) [0x7f7a0758044a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so(+0x18e8b5) [0x7f7a075808b5]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so(+0x18edc3) [0x7f7a07580dc3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so(+0x190583) [0x7f7a07582583]
./blender(ED_region_do_draw+0x6f3) [0xcdc023]
./blender() [0xa242e4]
./blender(wm_draw_update+0x5ac) [0xa2558c]
./blender(WM_main+0x28) [0xa20d68]
./blender(main+0x385) [0xa044d5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f7a25382ec5]
./blender() [0xa1d077]
```

After trying for many hours, I made no progress. So I reinstalled Ubuntu (running on a virtual machine), ran everything again with all the same errors. Obvsiously, it's crazy to try something over and over again expecting something different, but I thought reinstalling the OS would fix it. Literally did nothing.

On a side note, I find it odd that there aren't any 3rd party tutorials (outside of the blender website) that don't show how to setup a blender build environment using Ubuntu. Or maybe there is and I can't find it.

Let me know if I'm missing any additional info that will help and I'll include it.

Comment: @daltonfury42 why would that be?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working after installing Ubuntu 15.10. All the steps were replicated exactly.

The issue is fixed, but just to note: it appears to be using python 2.77. My understanding was that blender requires python 3.x. I will be investigating this.

Comment: yes blender uses python 3.5 now - the 2.77/python you see in the path is the python folder built for blender v2.77 to use, you will find the python version in it is 3.5

Comment: @sambler gotcha, that makes alot more sense. thanks